# What are the limits to the power of the City Remembrancer?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

I was re-watching the video from CGP Grey about the City of London.

[At 3:07](https://youtu.be/LrObZ_HZZUc?t=3m7s) he mentions the [City Remembrancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Remembrancer)

In the video he says:

> The City of London also has a representative in Parliament, The Remembrancer, whose job is to protects the City's special rights.
>    Because of this, laws passed by Parliament sometimes don't apply to the City of London: most notably voting reforms.

But the article from Wikipedia says:

> The parliamentary office is responsible for looking after the City of London's interests in Parliament with regard to all public legislation [...]
>   The Remembrancer is a Parliamentary agent and so can observe House of Commons proceedings from the under-gallery facing the Speaker's chair. However, that does not give the ability to participate in or influence the proceedings.
>   The Corporation in general, and the Remembrancer in particular, have no power to overrule Parliament, which has the right to make legislation affecting the City. For example, the Corporation needed to request a private Act of Parliament in 2002 to modernise its system of local elections; the Act notes, "The objects of this Act cannot be attained without the authority of Parliament".

So I am a little bit confused. What can the Remembrancer actually do? (and what can't they do?)

Comment: Short answer: The Remembancer is basically a fancy name for the City of London's lobbyist a.k.a. Governmental Affairs Officer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Remembrancer's Office influences Parliament by submitting evidence to parliamentary select committees.

Information source: [cityoflondon.gov.uk](https://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/business/Pages/remembrancers.aspx)

Here is more detail from the [same site](https://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/about-the-city/about-us/Pages/key-officers.aspx):

> In the contemporary context, this means day to day examination of Parliamentary business including examination of and briefing on proposed legislation and amendments to it, regular liaison with the Select Committees of both Houses and contact with officials in Government departments dealing with Parliamentary Bills. Liaison is also maintained with the City Office in Brussels and other Member States' permanent representations in relation to draft EU legislation.